transformer model error index out of range in self
I am trying to run a transformer model using my own dataset import json
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, random_split
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
import math

# Load JSON data
with open('/Users/osamafathi/mygp/dataset.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Corrected label mapping
label_mapping = {
    "Software Engineering": 0,
    "Information Systems": 1,
    "Artificial Intelligence": 2,
    "Computer Networks": 3,
    "Data Science": 4,
    "DevOps": 5,
    "Game Development": 6,
    "Human-Computer Interaction (HCI)": 7,
    "Cloud Computing": 8,
    "Cyber-Physical Systems": 9,
    "Software Development": 10,
    "Data Engineering": 11,
    "Web Development": 12,
    "Blockchain Technology": 13,
    "Robotics": 14,
    "Bioinformatics": 15,
    "Embedded Systems": 16,
    "Computer Science": 17,
    "Computer Science (General)": 18,
}

def convert_labels_to_integers(data, label_mapping):
    for item in data:
        item['recommended_major'] = label_mapping[item['recommended_major']]
    return data

data = convert_labels_to_integers(data, label_mapping)

# Define a dataset class
class MajorRecommendationDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, tokenizer, max_len):
        self.data = data
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_len = max_len

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        item = self.data[index]
        questions = item['questions']
        label = item['recommended_major']
        
        text = " ".join([q['question'] + " " + q['answer'] for q in questions])
        encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            text,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=self.max_len,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )

        input_ids = encoding['input_ids'].flatten()
        
        return {
            'input_ids': input_ids,
            'attention_mask': encoding['attention_mask'].flatten(),
            'label': torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long)
        }

# Custom Transformer Model components
class LayerNormalization(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, eps: float = 1e-6) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.eps = eps
        self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(features))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(features))

    def forward(self, x):
        mean = x.mean(dim=-1, keepdim=True)
        std = x.std(dim=-1, keepdim=True)
        return self.alpha * (x - mean) / (std + self.eps) + self.bias

class FeedForwardBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model: int, d_ff: int, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.linear_1 = nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear_2 = nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear_2(self.dropout(torch.relu(self.linear_1(x))))

class InputEmbeddings(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model: int, vocab_size: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.embedding(x) * math.sqrt(self.d_model)

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model: int, max_len: int, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.pe[:, :x.size(1), :]
        return self.dropout(x)

class ResidualConnection(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.norm = LayerNormalization(features)

    def forward(self, x, sublayer):
        return x + self.dropout(sublayer(self.norm(x)))

class MultiHeadAttentionBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model: int, h: int, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        assert d_model % h == 0, "d_model is not divisible by h"
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.h = h
        self.d_k = d_model // h
        self.w_q = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model, bias=False)
        self.w_k = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model, bias=False)
        self.w_v = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model, bias=False)
        self.w_o = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model, bias=False)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    @staticmethod
    def attention(query, key, value, mask, dropout: nn.Dropout):
        d_k = query.size(-1)
        scores = (query @ key.transpose(-2, -1)) / math.sqrt(d_k)
        if mask is not None:
            mask = mask.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2)
            scores = scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf'))
        p_attn = scores.softmax(dim=-1)
        if dropout is not None:
            p_attn = dropout(p_attn)
        return p_attn @ value, p_attn

    def forward(self, q, k, v, mask):
        batch_size = q.size(0)
        query = self.w_q(q).view(batch_size, -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
        key = self.w_k(k).view(batch_size, -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
        value = self.w_v(v).view(batch_size, -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
        x, self.attention_scores = MultiHeadAttentionBlock.attention(query, key, value, mask, self.dropout)
        x = x.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view(batch_size, -1, self.h * self.d_k)
        return self.w_o(x)

class EncoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, self_attention_block: MultiHeadAttentionBlock, feed_forward_block: FeedForwardBlock, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.self_attention_block = self_attention_block
        self.feed_forward_block = feed_forward_block
        self.residual_connections = nn.ModuleList([ResidualConnection(features, dropout) for _ in range(2)])

    def forward(self, x, src_mask):
        x = self.residual_connections[0](x, lambda x: self.self_attention_block(x, x, x, src_mask))
        x = self.residual_connections[1](x, self.feed_forward_block)
        return x

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, layers: nn.ModuleList) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = layers
        self.norm = LayerNormalization(features)

    def forward(self, x, mask):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, mask)
        return self.norm(x)

class DecoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, self_attention_block: MultiHeadAttentionBlock, cross_attention_block: MultiHeadAttentionBlock, feed_forward_block: FeedForwardBlock, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.self_attention_block = self_attention_block
        self.cross_attention_block = cross_attention_block
        self.feed_forward_block = feed_forward_block
        self.residual_connections = nn.ModuleList([ResidualConnection(features, dropout) for _ in range(3)])

    def forward(self, x, encoder_output, src_mask, tgt_mask):
        x = self.residual_connections[0](x, lambda x: self.self_attention_block(x, x, x, tgt_mask))
        x = self.residual_connections[1](x, lambda x: self.cross_attention_block(x, encoder_output, encoder_output, src_mask))
        x = self.residual_connections[2](x, self.feed_forward_block)
        return x

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, layers: nn.ModuleList) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = layers
        self.norm = LayerNormalization(features)

    def forward(self, x, encoder_output, src_mask, tgt_mask):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, encoder_output, src_mask, tgt_mask)
        return self.norm(x)

class ProjectionLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, vocab_size) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.proj = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.proj(x)

class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder: Encoder, decoder: Decoder, src_embed: InputEmbeddings, tgt_embed: InputEmbeddings, src_pos: PositionalEncoding, tgt_pos: PositionalEncoding, projection_layer: ProjectionLayer) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.src_embed = src_embed
        self.tgt_embed = tgt_embed
        self.src_pos = src_pos
        self.tgt_pos = tgt_pos
        self.projection_layer = projection_layer

    def encode(self, src, src_mask):
        src = self.src_embed(src)
        src = self.src_pos(src)
        return self.encoder(src, src_mask)

    def decode(self, encoder_output: torch.Tensor, src_mask: torch.Tensor, tgt: torch.Tensor, tgt_mask: torch.Tensor):
        tgt = self.tgt_embed(tgt)
        tgt = self.tgt_pos(tgt)
        return self.decoder(tgt, encoder_output, src_mask, tgt_mask)

    def project(self, x):
        return self.projection_layer(x)

def build_transformer(src_vocab_size: int, tgt_vocab_size: int, src_seq_len: int, tgt_seq_len: int, d_model: int = 512, N: int = 6, h: int = 8, dropout: float = 0.1, d_ff: int = 2048) -> Transformer:
    src_embed = InputEmbeddings(d_model, src_vocab_size)
    tgt_embed = InputEmbeddings(d_model, tgt_vocab_size)
    src_pos = PositionalEncoding(d_model, src_seq_len, dropout)
    tgt_pos = PositionalEncoding(d_model, tgt_seq_len, dropout)
    
    encoder_blocks = [EncoderBlock(d_model, MultiHeadAttentionBlock(d_model, h, dropout), FeedForwardBlock(d_model, d_ff, dropout), dropout) for _ in range(N)]
    decoder_blocks = [DecoderBlock(d_model, MultiHeadAttentionBlock(d_model, h, dropout), MultiHeadAttentionBlock(d_model, h, dropout), FeedForwardBlock(d_model, d_ff, dropout), dropout) for _ in range(N)]
    
    encoder = Encoder(d_model, nn.ModuleList(encoder_blocks))
    decoder = Decoder(d_model, nn.ModuleList(decoder_blocks))
    projection_layer = ProjectionLayer(d_model, tgt_vocab_size)
    
    transformer = Transformer(encoder, decoder, src_embed, tgt_embed, src_pos, tgt_pos, projection_layer)
    
    for p in transformer.parameters():
        if p.dim() > 1:
            nn.init.xavier_uniform_(p)
    
    return transformer

# Define the custom model training loop with early stopping and validation
def train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, device, num_epochs, patience):
    model = model.to(device)
    best_val_loss = float('inf')
    epochs_no_improve = 0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # Training
        model.train()
        train_loss = 0.0
        for batch in train_loader:
            input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
            attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
            labels = batch['label'].to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model.project(model.decode(model.encode(input_ids, attention_mask), attention_mask, input_ids, attention_mask))
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            
            train_loss += loss.item()

        avg_train_loss = train_loss / len(train_loader)
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], Average Training Loss: {avg_train_loss}')

        # Validation
        model.eval()
        val_loss = 0.0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for batch in val_loader:
                input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
                attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
                labels = batch['label'].to(device)

                outputs = model.project(model.decode(model.encode(input_ids, attention_mask), attention_mask, input_ids, attention_mask))
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                val_loss += loss.item()

        avg_val_loss = val_loss / len(val_loader)
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], Average Validation Loss: {avg_val_loss}')

        # Early stopping logic
        if avg_val_loss < best_val_loss:
            best_val_loss = avg_val_loss
            epochs_no_improve = 0
        else:
            epochs_no_improve += 1

        if epochs_no_improve >= patience:
            print("Early stopping triggered")
            break

# Tokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
max_len = 512

# Calculate the actual vocabulary size from the dataset
max_token_id = 0
for item in data:
    questions = item['questions']
    text = " ".join([q['question'] + " " + q['answer'] for q in questions])
    encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(
        text,
        add_special_tokens=True,
        max_length=max_len,
        padding='max_length',
        truncation=True,
        return_tensors='pt'
    )
    max_token_id = max(max_token_id, encoding['input_ids'].max().item())

vocab_size = max_token_id + 1

# Create dataset and dataloader
dataset = MajorRecommendationDataset(data, tokenizer, max_len)
train_size = int(0.8 * len(dataset))
val_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size])

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=False)

# Initialize custom transformer model, criterion, optimizer
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
src_vocab_size = vocab_size
tgt_vocab_size = len(label_mapping)  # Number of classes
src_seq_len = max_len
tgt_seq_len = max_len

model = build_transformer(src_vocab_size, tgt_vocab_size, src_seq_len, tgt_seq_len)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=2e-5)

# Train the model with early stopping and validation
train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, device, num_epochs=20, patience=3)# Load JSON data
with open('/Users/osamafathi/mygp/dataset.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Corrected label mapping
label_mapping = {
    "Software Engineering": 0,
    "Information Systems": 1,
    "Artificial Intelligence": 2,
    "Computer Networks": 3,
    "Data Science": 4,
    "DevOps": 5,
    "Game Development": 6,
    "Human-Computer Interaction (HCI)": 7,
    "Cloud Computing": 8,
    "Cyber-Physical Systems": 9,
    "Software Development": 10,
    "Data Engineering": 11,
    "Web Development": 12,
    "Blockchain Technology": 13,
    "Robotics": 14,
    "Bioinformatics": 15,
    "Embedded Systems": 16,
    "Computer Science": 17,
    "Computer Science (General)": 18,
}

def convert_labels_to_integers(data, label_mapping):
    for item in data:
        item['recommended_major'] = label_mapping[item['recommended_major']]
    return data

data = convert_labels_to_integers(data, label_mapping)

# Define a dataset class
class MajorRecommendationDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, tokenizer, max_len):
        self.data = data
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_len = max_len

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        item = self.data[index]
        questions = item['questions']
        label = item['recommended_major']
        
        text = " ".join([q['question'] + " " + q['answer'] for q in questions])
        encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            text,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=self.max_len,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )

        input_ids = encoding['input_ids'].flatten()
        
        return {
            'input_ids': input_ids,
            'attention_mask': encoding['attention_mask'].flatten(),
            'label': torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long)
        }

# Custom Transformer Model components
class LayerNormalization(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, eps: float = 1e-6) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.eps = eps
        self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(features))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(features))

    def forward(self, x):
        mean = x.mean(dim=-1, keepdim=True)
        std = x.std(dim=-1, keepdim=True)
        return self.alpha * (x - mean) / (std + self.eps) + self.bias

class FeedForwardBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model: int, d_ff: int, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.linear_1 = nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear_2 = nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear_2(self.dropout(torch.relu(self.linear_1(x))))

class InputEmbeddings(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model: int, vocab_size: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.embedding(x) * math.sqrt(self.d_model)

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model: int, max_len: int, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.pe[:, :x.size(1), :]
        return self.dropout(x)

class ResidualConnection(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.norm = LayerNormalization(features)

    def forward(self, x, sublayer):
        return x + self.dropout(sublayer(self.norm(x)))

class MultiHeadAttentionBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model: int, h: int, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        assert d_model % h == 0, "d_model is not divisible by h"
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.h = h
        self.d_k = d_model // h
        self.w_q = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model, bias=False)
        self.w_k = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model, bias=False)
        self.w_v = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model, bias=False)
        self.w_o = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model, bias=False)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    @staticmethod
    def attention(query, key, value, mask, dropout: nn.Dropout):
        d_k = query.size(-1)
        scores = (query @ key.transpose(-2, -1)) / math.sqrt(d_k)
        if mask is not None:
            mask = mask.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2)
            scores = scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf'))
        p_attn = scores.softmax(dim=-1)
        if dropout is not None:
            p_attn = dropout(p_attn)
        return p_attn @ value, p_attn

    def forward(self, q, k, v, mask):
        batch_size = q.size(0)
        query = self.w_q(q).view(batch_size, -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
        key = self.w_k(k).view(batch_size, -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
        value = self.w_v(v).view(batch_size, -1, self.h, self.d_k).transpose(1, 2)
        x, self.attention_scores = MultiHeadAttentionBlock.attention(query, key, value, mask, self.dropout)
        x = x.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view(batch_size, -1, self.h * self.d_k)
        return self.w_o(x)

class EncoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, self_attention_block: MultiHeadAttentionBlock, feed_forward_block: FeedForwardBlock, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.self_attention_block = self_attention_block
        self.feed_forward_block = feed_forward_block
        self.residual_connections = nn.ModuleList([ResidualConnection(features, dropout) for _ in range(2)])

    def forward(self, x, src_mask):
        x = self.residual_connections[0](x, lambda x: self.self_attention_block(x, x, x, src_mask))
        x = self.residual_connections[1](x, self.feed_forward_block)
        return x

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, layers: nn.ModuleList) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = layers
        self.norm = LayerNormalization(features)

    def forward(self, x, mask):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, mask)
        return self.norm(x)

class DecoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, self_attention_block: MultiHeadAttentionBlock, cross_attention_block: MultiHeadAttentionBlock, feed_forward_block: FeedForwardBlock, dropout: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.self_attention_block = self_attention_block
        self.cross_attention_block = cross_attention_block
        self.feed_forward_block = feed_forward_block
        self.residual_connections = nn.ModuleList([ResidualConnection(features, dropout) for _ in range(3)])

    def forward(self, x, encoder_output, src_mask, tgt_mask):
        x = self.residual_connections[0](x, lambda x: self.self_attention_block(x, x, x, tgt_mask))
        x = self.residual_connections[1](x, lambda x: self.cross_attention_block(x, encoder_output, encoder_output, src_mask))
        x = self.residual_connections[2](x, self.feed_forward_block)
        return x

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features: int, layers: nn.ModuleList) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = layers
        self.norm = LayerNormalization(features)

    def forward(self, x, encoder_output, src_mask, tgt_mask):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, encoder_output, src_mask, tgt_mask)
        return self.norm(x)

class ProjectionLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, vocab_size) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.proj = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.proj(x)

class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder: Encoder, decoder: Decoder, src_embed: InputEmbeddings, tgt_embed: InputEmbeddings, src_pos: PositionalEncoding, tgt_pos: PositionalEncoding, projection_layer: ProjectionLayer) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.src_embed = src_embed
        self.tgt_embed = tgt_embed
        self.src_pos = src_pos
        self.tgt_pos = tgt_pos
        self.projection_layer = projection_layer

    def encode(self, src, src_mask):
        src = self.src_embed(src)
        src = self.src_pos(src)
        return self.encoder(src, src_mask)

    def decode(self, encoder_output: torch.Tensor, src_mask: torch.Tensor, tgt: torch.Tensor, tgt_mask: torch.Tensor):
        tgt = self.tgt_embed(tgt)
        tgt = self.tgt_pos(tgt)
        return self.decoder(tgt, encoder_output, src_mask, tgt_mask)

    def project(self, x):
        return self.projection_layer(x)

def build_transformer(src_vocab_size: int, tgt_vocab_size: int, src_seq_len: int, tgt_seq_len: int, d_model: int = 512, N: int = 6, h: int = 8, dropout: float = 0.1, d_ff: int = 2048) -> Transformer:
    src_embed = InputEmbeddings(d_model, src_vocab_size)
    tgt_embed = InputEmbeddings(d_model, tgt_vocab_size)
    src_pos = PositionalEncoding(d_model, src_seq_len, dropout)
    tgt_pos = PositionalEncoding(d_model, tgt_seq_len, dropout)
    
    encoder_blocks = [EncoderBlock(d_model, MultiHeadAttentionBlock(d_model, h, dropout), FeedForwardBlock(d_model, d_ff, dropout), dropout) for _ in range(N)]
    decoder_blocks = [DecoderBlock(d_model, MultiHeadAttentionBlock(d_model, h, dropout), MultiHeadAttentionBlock(d_model, h, dropout), FeedForwardBlock(d_model, d_ff, dropout), dropout) for _ in range(N)]
    
    encoder = Encoder(d_model, nn.ModuleList(encoder_blocks))
    decoder = Decoder(d_model, nn.ModuleList(decoder_blocks))
    projection_layer = ProjectionLayer(d_model, tgt_vocab_size)
    
    transformer = Transformer(encoder, decoder, src_embed, tgt_embed, src_pos, tgt_pos, projection_layer)
    
    for p in transformer.parameters():
        if p.dim() > 1:
            nn.init.xavier_uniform_(p)
    
    return transformer

# Define the custom model training loop with early stopping and validation
def train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, device, num_epochs, patience):
    model = model.to(device)
    best_val_loss = float('inf')
    epochs_no_improve = 0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # Training
        model.train()
        train_loss = 0.0
        for batch in train_loader:
            input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
            attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
            labels = batch['label'].to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model.project(model.decode(model.encode(input_ids, attention_mask), attention_mask, input_ids, attention_mask))
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            
            train_loss += loss.item()

        avg_train_loss = train_loss / len(train_loader)
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], Average Training Loss: {avg_train_loss}')

        # Validation
        model.eval()
        val_loss = 0.0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for batch in val_loader:
                input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
                attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
                labels = batch['label'].to(device)

                outputs = model.project(model.decode(model.encode(input_ids, attention_mask), attention_mask, input_ids, attention_mask))
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                val_loss += loss.item()

        avg_val_loss = val_loss / len(val_loader)
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], Average Validation Loss: {avg_val_loss}')

        # Early stopping logic
        if avg_val_loss < best_val_loss:
            best_val_loss = avg_val_loss
            epochs_no_improve = 0
        else:
            epochs_no_improve += 1

        if epochs_no_improve >= patience:
            print("Early stopping triggered")
            break

# Tokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
max_len = 512

# Calculate the actual vocabulary size from the dataset
max_token_id = 0
for item in data:
    questions = item['questions']
    text = " ".join([q['question'] + " " + q['answer'] for q in questions])
    encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(
        text,
        add_special_tokens=True,
        max_length=max_len,
        padding='max_length',
        truncation=True,
        return_tensors='pt'
    )
    max_token_id = max(max_token_id, encoding['input_ids'].max().item())

vocab_size = max_token_id + 1

# Create dataset and dataloader
dataset = MajorRecommendationDataset(data, tokenizer, max_len)
train_size = int(0.8 * len(dataset))
val_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size])

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=False)

# Initialize custom transformer model, criterion, optimizer
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
src_vocab_size = vocab_size
tgt_vocab_size = len(label_mapping)  # Number of classes
src_seq_len = max_len
tgt_seq_len = max_len

model = build_transformer(src_vocab_size, tgt_vocab_size, src_seq_len, tgt_seq_len)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=2e-5)

# Train the model with early stopping and validation
train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, device, num_epochs=20, patience=3)

that was the entire code with the training loop and every thing but I get this error IndexError
index out of range in self
I know that the input coming from the dataset is too large and embedding of the model can't handle. it but I don't know how to fix it

Please add your error stack trace.
